# How to update Multiple records in array through relationship laravel

Tags: laravel

Below is my request to be updated , i succesfully updated booking model , but how can i update BookingCostCalculation model . Booking hasMany BookingCostCalculation

```
{
    "booking": {
        "package_id": 4,
        "package_name": "masti ",
        "first_name": "shubham",
        "last_name": "pradhan",
        "email": "jioyhgjvn@gmail.com",
       "cc_email":"jio1@gmail.com,jio2@gmail.com",
        "phone": 9890989898,
        "total_pax": "5",
        "total_cost": "5000",
        "total_discount": "5000",
        "total_gst": "5000",
        "total_amount_to_pay": "3000",
        "comment":"hiii",
        "cost": [
            {
                "package_itinerary_id": "1",
                "travel_mode_id": 1,
                "occupancy_id": 1,
                "package_price": 10000,
                "package_discount": 500,
               
            },
            {
                "package_itinerary_id": "1",
                "travel_mode_id": 1,
                "occupancy_id": 1,
                "package_price": 10000,
                "package_discount": 500,
                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My Controller code is

```
$Booking = Booking::find($id);
            
 
            $bookingData = $request->booking;
            $Booking->update($bookingData);
            // dd($bookingData['cost']);
            if (is_array($bookingData['cost'])) {
                $Booking->BookingCostCalculation()->update([$bookingData['cost']]);
            }
```

how can i do it
i stored data through createMany
is there any method to update many

Comment: try updateOrCreate instead of update [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method]

Answer (score 0):

Try using updateOrCreate method.

```
$Booking->BookingCostCalculation()->updateOrCreate($bookingData['cost']);
```